# Remove one item from selected elements in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a multiselect with many options. When 'everybody' is selected it removes other selected, if other are selected and the 'everybody' is selected it should remove it.

To remove the other and keep the item 'everybody' it's ok. But I have problem to keep other and only remove everybody.

For the moment I have something like :

```
  resetGroupSelectionWhenEverybody: function() {
    $(".group_ids").on("select2:select", function (e){
      if (e.params.data.text === 'everybody') {
        $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2({width: '50%'}).val(group_everybody_id).trigger("change");
      } else {
        if ($('[title="everybody"]').length > 0) {
          var idToRemove = 0;
          groupIdsData = $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2('data');
          groupIdsData.forEach(function(e, i) {
            if (e.text === 'everybody') {
              idToRemove = i;
            }
          });
          groupIdsData.splice(idToRemove, 1);
          $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2({'data': groupIdsData}).trigger("change");
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

With this code `groupIdsData` is tonly the selected elements I want (all expect `everybody`'s group). But after I'm stuck to change the view. `select2({'data': groupIdsData})` doesn't seems to be the right choice.

Few things :

1. I don't think I'm setting the `idToRemove` properly
2. What the best way to update the value of the select2 multiselect? It seems [it can be a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21968517/2747638)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `select2('val')` to get a array of ids, and then work with this. Code is better using `.val()` not full select2 objects.

```
  resetGroupSelectionWhenEverybody: function() {
    $(".group_ids").on("select2:select", function (e){
      if (e.params.data.text === 'everybody') {
        $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2({width: '50%'}).val(group_everybody_id).trigger("change");
      } else {
        if ($('[title="everybody"]').length > 0) {
          groupIds = $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2('val');
          groupToKeep = groupIds.splice( $.inArray(group_everybody_id, groupIds), 1);
          $('#scheduled_publication_groups_ids').select2({width: '50%'}).val(groupToKeep).trigger("change");
        }
      }
    });
  },
```